# How do you make repeatable backgrounds for things in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

How do you make repeatable backgrounds for things in XAML?

Back when I was working with HTML, I remember having bitmaps as backgrounds for either a page or for an area.

Now I find I want this same sort of thing in my XAML page for Silverlight.  How do I do that?  How do I make it repeatable so that the image pattern exists across, for example, a header area no matter how wide the browser window is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPF it's pretty simple. In Silverlight, it isn't. However, this article gives an example of how to use a pixel shader to accomplish the task:

http://www.silverlightplayground.org/post/2009/03/22/Silverlight-30-Tile-Effect-with-a-Pixel-Shader.aspx

Another article [here](http://silverscratch.blogspot.com/2010/09/tiled-image-brush-for-silverlight.html) uses the same technique.